# How to execute a second javascript function after changing a button's id?

Tags: javascript

I have an html button where I change the value and id in an attempt to execute a javascript function based on the new ID.

From this;

```
<button id="Start" class="Button">Start</button>
```

to this;

```
<button id="Stop" class="Button">Stop</button>
```

The intent is for the user to click on the Start button to execute the associated function and change the existing button into a Stop button to execute its associated function. One button with two separate tasks.

```
var mySocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.102:5678/");
window.onload = function() {
    var StartST = document.getElementById('Start');
    var StopST = document.getElementById('Stop');
    var socketStatus = document.getElementById('usercontent');
    if (StartST) {
        StartST.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            StartST.innerHTML = "Stop";
            StartST.id = "Stop";
            mySocket.send('start');
            socketStatus.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin','<div class="received">Start -> ' + StartST.id + '</div>\n');
            e.preventDefault();
        })
    }

    if (StopST) {
        StopST.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            mySocket.send('stop');
            StopST.innerHTML = "Start";
            StopST.id = "Start";
            socketStatus.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin','<div class="received">Stop</div>\n');
            e.preventDefault();
        })
    }
};
```

The issue is I cannot execute the Stop button function and I am not sure how to implement delegation to get it to work correctly.

Comment: The stop button's eventlistener never gets added in the first place. Instead of changing the id of the button, just put both in your document and set the stop button to `display: none;` When the start button is clicked, hide it and show the stop button. And vice-versa. (you can also track the state and use a single event listener that handled start and stop)

Comment: See: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). As mentioned this is no reason to change the id for this task, it's something you should avoid doing.